# Unit tests failing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

I recently "upgraded" from Visual Studio 2012 to 2017, and now a number of tests which pass when run in 2012, fail in 2017. Application-specific Assertions fail and I am also getting the following exceptions:

1. > Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException: UnitTestIsolation instrumentation failed to initialize. Please restart Visual Studio and rerun this test (needless to say, a restart does not resolve the issue)
2. > System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

All code, options, and settings are identical in both environments. I am using Microsoft's testing framework, not NUnit, XUnit, etc. The code is in VB.Net. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to recreate Fakes assembly reference?

Comment: No. Apparently that option isn't available in the Professional version. Will look into upgrading to Enterprise. Thanks.

Comment: You would not be able to Run test cases using Fakes assembly in Professional version.

Answer (score 0):

The option to use Fakes Assemblies isn't available in the Professional version. We will need to upgrade to the Enterprise Edition, or continue using 2012.